# How to treat N<T> as N<const T>?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node<T>* next;
};

template <typename T>
struct X
{
    Node<T>* node;

    X(Node<T>* node) : node(node) {}

    X<const T> getConst() const
    {
        return X<const T>(node);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Node<int> node{ nullptr };

    X<int> x(&node);

    auto constX = x.getConst();
}
```

This code doesn't compile since I'm returning `X<const T>` and the constructor of `X<const T>` requires a `Node<const T>` and I'm passing `Node<T>`. How to overcome this problem? since `T` can be treated as `const T` anyways.